# How can I reduce a rough opening height 1-1/4"?

Tags: doors, framing, rough-in

I'm building a new master bedroom closet.  The wife wants a specific 30x80" door which requires a rough-in of 32x82.  Unfortunately, the measurement from the top plate to the subfloor is 83 1/4".  I'm not sure how to handle this.  The jack studs for the rough-in would be 82" which would mean no top plate would fit (A 2x4 is 1.5" thick and I only have 1.25" available).

Do I just not put a top plate, make the jack stud 83 1/4" and just deal with the extra 1 1/4 at the top of the pre-hung casing?  Do I try to trim the 1.5" of the top plate down to 1.25" somehow?

Greg

Comment: If you are building it why can you not just make the R.O. the size you need ? I.E. cut the jack studs to the length you need. OR just put a 1 x 4  ( 3/4 thick ) up against the the top plate, the remaining gap from top of door jamb will be covered by trim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cut a 2x4 to length and rip 1-1/4" off each side. Put those up against the top plate, one inside and one outside. The half inch hollow in between is inconsequential.

```
End view
 _____
|_____| <-- top wall plate
|_| |_| <-- 1-1/4" high rippers
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to stack two furring strips on each side of the top plate. The one I'm looking at right now is 5/8" thick, stacked would be 1.25".

Comment: The one what? Do you happen to have some 5/8" plywood scrap on hand?

Comment: @isherwood  The  furring strip I had.

Comment: I don't know what that is. In my experience, all furring strips are custom-made. Does someone sell a product labelled "furring strip"?

Comment: You can get them off the rack at HD. Common: 1 in. x 2 in. x 8 ft.; Actual: 0.656 in. x 1.468 in. x 96 in.  so my bad, two stacked would be 1/16" too high. the one I had looked like 5'8". + to you

Comment: 1/16" is certainly within framing tolerances. :)